# my png file is not showing in my picturebox

Tags: c#

I want display an image in my picture box but when I run the code everything else works except the image isn't displayed. Here is the relevant code:

```
Image[] deadWoman = new Image[5]; //this array will hold the images of bit and pieces of katie

deadWoman[0] = Image.FromFile("F:/Jers Hangman Game/Jers Hangman Game/Resources/katie-hopkins.jpeg");


private void MainPic_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics katie = e.Graphics; // creates a graphics object for the picture box

    if (numWrongGuesses > 0)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(deadWoman[0], 20, 20,60,60);
    }
}
```

Comment: My crystal ball says that you forgot to call `MainPic.Invalidate()` when you change the *numWrongGuesses* variable.  Simple to verify, minimize and restore the window and check if you now see the dead woman.

Comment: You crystal ball is spot on...maybe you should post it as an answer

Comment: now that I look at it that was what @Patrick Hofman said but I didn't understand until it was typed out in front of  me

Comment: Yes, he got it.  I already upvoted his post, you just have to mark it as the answer to close your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the image is never repainted, that's why you don't see it when `numWrongGuesses` is updated. You should [`Invalidate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.invalidate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the `PictureBox` in order to see the update.

I would advise to set the image though, and simply use `Visible = true` and `Visible = false` for showing and hiding. You could even set the `BackgroundImage` if you need to create some overlay effect.

Comment: The image will be changing depending in the position in the array so making it visible wouldn't work in this case, unless I changed the code so that a variable went into deadWoman e.g deadWoman[var]. Why would that help though?

Comment: Why not set the image when you need it set? No need in painting it yourself.

Comment: Whats the difference in setting it and painting it?

Comment: When you set it Windows Forms is responsible for paining and repainting it. Now you are responsible yourself. (Think of reinventing the wheel. No need to.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't override `Paint` in order to put an `Image` object into a `PictureBox`. Just use the property:

```
MainPic.Image = deadWoman[0];
```

You can also do this in the WinForms designer, as long as the `Image` is a resource.

Also, you can hide and show your image by the `.Visible` property:

```
MainPic.Visible = numWrongGuesses > 0;
```

Comment: would I put  MainPic.image in the MainPic_Paint method?

Comment: Remove the Paint method and put that in your `InitializeComponent` method.